# Não consigo quebrar de linha usando JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Bom dia, estou com certas dificuldades em tentar quebrar uma linha usando [b]\n[/b] do javascript. O código está funcionando perfeitamente, o que acontece é que na hora de exibir, fica mais ou menos assim:

**Meu nick:** Viniciusn**Como descobri o servidor:** YouTuben**Eu quero jogar porque:** Gostei do servidor

Tipo o \n não tá quebrando a linha, mas ele aparece ali no final de cada string que eu coloco, o que será que está acontecendo?

```js
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('[name="post"]').click(function () {
            var nick = $('#field0').val();
            var descobriu = $('#field1').val();
            var motivo = $('#field2').val();
            $('input[name="subject"]').val('[ Whitelist] ' + nick + ' ');
            $('input#message').val('[b]Meu nick:[/b] ' + nick + ' <br>[b]Como descobri o servidor:[/b] ' + descobriu + ' \n[b]Eu quero jogar porque:[/b] ' + motivo);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: use <br> em vez de \n

Comment: Eu tentei usar o <br> porém no meu fórum ele aparece a tag <br> ao invés de quebrar linha

Comment: Já tentou `'\\n'`?

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado nicematt!

Comment: Ei agora não tá funcionando mais, ta aparecendo assim http://i.imgur.com/RwwmnRj.jpg

Comment: Eu coloquei as duas barras \\

Comment: `<script>
    $(function () {
        $('[name="post"]').click(function () {
            var nick = $('#field0').val();
            var descobriu = $('#field1').val();
            var motivo = $('#field2').val();
            $('input[name="subject"]').val('[ Whitelist] ' + nick + ' ');
            $('input#message').val('[b]Meu nick:[/b] ' + nick + '\\n[b]Como descobri o servidor:[/b] ' + descobriu + '\\n[b]Eu quero jogar porque:[/b] ' + motivo);
        });
    });
</script> `

Comment: Eu também não sei, parece q ele não tá lendo a primeira barra

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627902/new-line-in-text-area?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em vez de colocar em um input, defina um  `<p id="paragrafo"> <p>`
depois você usa a sua chamada alterando o id do elemento:

```
 $('paragrafo').val('[b]Meu nick:[/b] ' + nick + ' <br>[b]Como descobri o servidor:[/b] ' + descobriu + ' \n[b]Eu quero jogar porque:[/b] ' + motivo);
```

Comment: Já tinha sanado essa duvida, mesmo assim vou dar um gostei na sua resposta caso alguém tenha a mesma pergunta que eu.

Comment: beleza! Abraços.

Answer (score 2):

Não vejo muito sentido em querer usar quebra de linha em `input`. Neste caso, o adequado seria uma `textarea`.

Basta usar `\n` para quebrar as linhas, veja funcionando:

```js
var nick = 'XYZ';
var descobriu = 'por acaso';
var motivo = 'achei legal';

$('#message').val('[b]Meu nick:[/b] ' + nick + '\n[b]Como descobri o servidor:[/b] ' + descobriu + ' \n[b]Eu quero jogar porque:[/b] ' + motivo);
```

```css
#message {width:80%}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="message"></textarea>
```

Comment: Então, substitui pra textarea só que no meu forum não funciona de jeito nenhum o **\n** ele aparece como uma string

Comment: Pode ser que o problema esteja na parte da exibição, eu respondi em cima do código que está na pergunta, que só mostra a entrada dos dados. Pode ser que seu fórum tenha alguma conversão na hora de gravar os dados, mas sem ver o código, é complicado. Se não achar solução para exibir ou salvar corretamente os dados, abra uma pergunta sobre a exibição, mas ponha a parte do código que mostra os dados com problema na tela.